# React Lazy imports using named imports

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

How could I import named imports using lazy syntax?

Before we could use

```
import { MainComponent, Component1, Component2 } from './components';
```

How to achieve something like this (although this does not work)?:

```
const { MainComponent, Component1, Component2 } = React.lazy(() => import('./components'));
```

Comment: Good question. I don't think it's possible tho. You should export default an object that contains all the components

Answer (score 4):

Currently named imports are not supported for `React.lazy`:

> This RFC has a limited surface. It's targeted at the main use case we want to start handling (default imports). There is a door open for supporting named imports in future RFCs, but it is out of scope of this one. This one is intentionally very limited. We expect to understand this problem space more within the next several months and then we can revisit that discussion with a better understanding.
> [reactjs/rfcs#64 (comment)](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/64#issuecomment-431507924)

Answer (score 1):

React does not support named export

In [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#named-exports) you can find an example of how to create intermediate module

This means another file for each import. There is no better syntax at the moment, but we hope to have it in the future

```
// ManyComponents.js
export const MyComponent = /* ... */;
export const MyUnusedComponent = /* ... */;


// MyComponent.js
export { MyComponent as default } from "./ManyComponents.js";

// MyApp.js
import React, { lazy } from 'react';
const MyComponent = lazy(() => import("./MyComponent.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We wanted to avoid usage of default exports in my team so we wrote a CustomLazy component in TS:

```
/**
 * Improvement on top of React.lazy() that allows lazy rendering of named imports
 * Usage:
 *
 *  -- alternative to import { primary } from './Button'
 *  const PrimaryButton = CustomLazy(() => import('./Button'),'primary');
 *
 *  -- get the default import
 *  CustomLazy(() => import('./Button'), 'default');
 *
 *  -- or
 *  CustomLazy(() => import('./Button'));
 *
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-imports
import { ComponentType, lazy } from 'react';

type CustomLazyProps = <T extends ComponentType<React.PropsWithChildren<any>>>(
  thenable: () => Promise<{
    [name: string]: T;
  }>,
  name?: string
) => React.LazyExoticComponent<T>;

const CustomLazy: CustomLazyProps = (resolver, name = 'default') => {
  return lazy(async () => {
    const resolved = await resolver();
    return { default: resolved[name] };
  });
};

export default CustomLazy;
```

Answer (score -3):

Haven't tried it but something like this should work:

```
const { MainComponent, Component1, Component2 } = React.lazy(() => 
import('./components')).then(module => ({
    default: {
        MainComponent: module.MainComponent,
        Component1: module.Component1,
        Component2: module.Component2,
}));
```